# Preventing multiple notifyIcons when not actually closing application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms

I want to be able to keep just one notifyIcon without others crowding up my taskbar when I 'Snooze' my form. The design is such that it should not be able to be closed (outside of closing down the process) so the controlbar has been removed. It can only be hidden by pressing the provided button at which point it minimizes to the taskbar, but for some reason when I test it a few times I end up with a taskbar full of icons that don't disappear until I hover over them.

I'd appreciate any advice

Comment: It is a bug in your code, you are not calling its Dispose() method for some reason.  We can't see it from here.  Tends to be likely when you tag [wpf] since you no longer have the automatic disposal that the Form class takes care of.

Comment: Can you say where I should be calling Dipose()?

Comment: When ever you want the icon to disappear of course.  Tends to be most sensible in an event handler for a Window's Closed event.